# Did the Nazgûl wear their 9 rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

Did the Nazgûl wear their 9 rings?

Wikipedia is singularly unhelpful:

> Some passages in the novel suggest that the Nazgûl wore their rings, while others suggest that Sauron actually held them.

(with no references).

Can someone please shed light on which version is more supported by Tolkien's work?